# Github: Pull request approval access

Tags: github

I have an issue, I have a team (they are added into Github package's teams list with Write perm) of external developers, I want to restrict their ability to approve each other's PRs.
Meaning other team/users should be probably a different set of perms.
How can I do it? I wasn't able to find this on Github.

PS.

I tried adding this to .github/CODEOWNERS (also enabled require owner review)

```
* @company/company-devs some-special-developer
```

but @other_company/devs <- were still able to approve

Comment: I don't think you can restrict anybody's access to approve PRs, however, you can restrict whose approvals count towards the minimal approvals check

Comment: Some organization use bots or github actions to implement this sort of logic. E.g., rather than using the gitub "approve", people leave a `/approve` comment, and the bots checks to ensure that these come from both teams before actually approving the PR (this means only the bot/workflow has the ability to approve).

Comment: @larsks do you know what kind of bots these are?